# Python: Server-Client connection - Error: Server crash

Tags: python

1. I open the server
2. I open the client
3. The client sends "connectrequest" to server
4. Server recvs "connectrequest"
5. Server sends "connected" to client
6. Client recvs "connected" from server
7. Client print "Connected"!
8. Server crashs and I cannot found why (Also I cant see the error).

Server:

```
from socket import *;

iSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM );
iSocket.bind( ( "", 4325 ) );

while True:

    recv_data, addr = iSocket.recvfrom( 2048 );

    if addr[ 0 ] == "127.0.0.1":

        #stuff

    elif recv_data == "on":
        print "New connection:", addr[ 0 ];

    elif recv_data == "connectrequest":
        iSocket.sendto( "connected", addr );
```

Client:

```
import time;
import select;
from socket import *;

address = ( '192.168.0.101', 4325 );

iSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM );
iSocket.connect( address );

reconnect = 10;
last_reconnect = 0;
connected = False;

while connected == False:

    if last_reconnect <= int( time.time( ) ) + reconnect:
        print "Connecting...";
        iSocket.sendto( "connectrequest", address );

    data_available = select.select( [ iSocket ], [ ], [ ], 11 )

    if data_available[ 0 ]:
        recv_data, addr = iSocket.recvfrom( 2048 );

        if recv_data == "connected":
            connected = True;
            print "Connected!";

iSocket.sendto( "on", address );

while True:

    recv_data, addr = iSocket.recvfrom( 2048 );
    print recv_data, addr;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Do you get a traceback or does it segfault? Also, you don't need to put semicolons at the end of each line in Python.

Comment: Why are you using UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`, `recvfrom`, and `sendto`) if you want a connection? The whole point of UDP is that it's _not_ a connected protocol.

Comment: The console closes unexpectedly.

You are right, I should use tcp protocol xD I forget that...

Btw is there any error in my code?

Comment: How are you running this code? If you've got a console open, and you type `python server.py`, your script cannot make the console close. If you're double-clicking the script in Finder/Explorer/whatever, stop doing that and run it from the command line, so you can see what the error is.

Comment: And yes, obviously there is an error in your code. It may be that where you're possibly calling `sendto` on a listener socket and passing an address that nobody is listening to, you get some kind of `socket.error` exception. Or maybe not. Who knows? It'll be a lot easier to guess if we know what actually happens, instead of having to think of all possible things that could go wrong.

Comment: I make a exe file because I running the server on a PC that hasn't python installed, but I'll install and try again. Wait a few minutes, I will post the error.

Comment: In general, you really want to test your code _before_ you start creating non-debuggable release packages… But you should still be able to run the .exe from the command line; it's just `server.exe` instead of `python server.py`. Assuming this isn't a GUI app, and you haven't done anything funky in `py2exe`/`cx_freeze`/whatever, that should have the exact same effect.